# O que acontece com a variável i neste algoritmo? Algoritmo de inversão de sequência

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Boa noite. Comecei a estudar estrutura de dados tendo como apoio o livro *Estrutura de Dados e Seus Algoritmos 2ª ed* (SZWARCFITER/MARKENZON). O primeiro algoritmo do livro trata de inverter os elementos da sequência no vetor, trocando a posição do último elemento com o primeiro, sucessivamente até o último elemento. O algoritmo é este:

```
algoritmo 1.1: Inversão de uma sequencia
   para i <- 1...[n/2] faça
       temp <- S[i]
       S[i] <- S[n - i + 1]
       S[n -i + 1] <- temp
```

Eu escrevi o algoritmo em *Portugol* e adicionei um trecho que completa a lista.

```
var


S:VETOR[1..10] de INTEIRO
  i,j,temp,t: INTEIRO
inicio

para i de 1 ate 10 faca
     S[i] <- i
fimpara

para i de 1 ate 10 faca
     escreva(S[i], " ")
fimpara

 Escreval(" ")

 para j de 1 ate 10 faca
      temp <- S[j]
      S[j] <- S[10-j+1]
      t <- S[10-j+1]
      se (j>5) entao
              S[j] <- -j+i
              t <- -j+i
      fimse
      escreva(t, " ")
 fimpara

fimalgoritmo
```

A minha dúvida é com relação ao à variável *i*. Porquê ela assume o valor 11 após imprimir a lista? Antes de chegar a esse código, eu usava uma variável auxiliar *k*, para listar os números menores que 6 em ordem inversa, mas percebi que *i* assumia o valor *11*, então passei a fazer *-j+i*. Alguém me explica isso?

Comment: Pelo pouco que sei de algorítimos, seu vetor não deveria começar no "0" ?

Comment: Sim, ele começa do 0. S[1] = posição zero do vetor S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha pelo que conheço de algoritmo, portugol e tudo mais, se começar em 0 ou 1 ou 2 tanto faz, o que importa é que você saiba o que esta fazendo, continuando, o que você pode fazer é o seguinte: na hora que você vai atribuir os valores de i em outro vetor, ao mesmo tempo que você atribui o inverso já atribui novamente, ele montado no vetor principal.

vou tentar explicar com um exemplo:

```
funcao inversao():inteiro
var
inversor :vetor [0..9] de inteiro // vetor inversor
contador_inversor:inteiro
inicio
escreval (" A ORDEM INVERSA É: ")
contador <- 10
para contador_inversor de 0 ate 12 faca
     inversor[contador_inversor] <- c[contador]
     contador <- contador - 1
fimpara
para contador de 0 ate 12 faca
     c[contador] <- inversor[contador]
     escreva(" ", c[contador])
fimpara
escreval(" ")
fimfuncao
```

eu lhe dou esse exemplo para você pegar como base, pois é de um projeto que eu fiz, se não serviu me fala que eu te auxilio melhor, mas tenta interpretar a partir deste que para mim funciona aqui.

Comment: Entendi. O que você fez é uma alternativa para o problema. A minha questão é quanto ao comportamento da variável i e porquê ela assume o valor 11, uma vez que o número de iterações é 10.

Comment: porque a cada interação ele acrescenta 1, no caso soma 1 a variavel i, digamos que ela começa em 1, faz o laço, acrescenta mais 1 ficaria i <- i + 1 mas o laço para ate faça ja faz isso, de somar, i + 1, e dai deopis de somar, esse 1 ai na variavel e atribuir a i, ele compara com o valor ATE no caso 10 se nao for 10 entao ele executa o laço e acrescenta mais um ate chegar em 10 chegando em 10 ele executa o laço novamente, e acrescenta + 1 sendo 11 e dai ele cai fora do laço pois o laço somente pedia até 10  e finalizando! seria isso? fui bem claro? ou ficou alguma coisa sem entender?

Comment: Isso que eu queria saber. Tinha uma leve intuição, mas não a certeza de que isso poderia ser do programa Visualg, não do algoritmo. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

O exemplo do livro em JavaScript:

```
S = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20];

function Inverso(S)
{
    for(i = 0; i < (S.length / 2); i++)
    {
        let Temp = S[i]
        
        S[i] = S[S.length - (i + 1)]
        S[S.length - (i + 1)] = Temp
    }
    return S;
}
```